# VPN Connection Issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn

I have setup a VPN connection to a Draytek Vigor 2860 Series router using L2TP with IPSec and is working fine when I start the connection using the icon provided in the networks menu in the system tray:

System Tray Connection:

[image]

Now what I have done is made the connection available to everyone, thus allowing the connection to be made before the users log into the PC.

The issue that I am having is that when I try to establish the VPN connection at the login screen it states that my username or password is incorrect, and this error is returned every time I try to connect:

Login Failure:

[image]

What I have figured out is that if I don’t provide a password then a login form pops up asking me to re-enter my credentials, so I put in my password and click ok:

Login Prompt:

[image]

Finally, it comes up with an error window, and then once I click redial, the connection establishes and is stable:

Error Prompt:

[image]

Established Connection:

[image]

Does anyone know If I have configured something incorrectly, or if this is a bug with Windows?

I have searched all over the web for this issue but have yet to come across a resolution.